# Image rotation issue in angular6 when we upload from mobile camera

Tags: javascript, angular6, exif, image-upload

When I upload image using mobile camera, it's showing rotated, does anyone know why?

I am using following code:

```html
<input id="upload" class="file-upload__input" type="file" name="image" 
       (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
<div>
  <img src="{{url}}">
</div>
```

My ts file is like following:

```js
onFileChanged(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (events: any) => {
      this.url = events.target.result;
    };
  }
}
```

It's showing rotated image, please let me know if there is relevant working code.

Thanks in advance